# create new Bounded Type Parameter

Tags: java, bounded-types

I'm looking to implement a generic search function to basically look if a mouse click is within one of several list of rectangles (of varying types, all children of G3_gRect). When nothing is found, it should return a new object of type T with a property defining it as being invalid (as opposed to other things that it could be).

This all works fine until I try to make it return the generic type T.
What can I do differently to make this work?

This breaks in the last line when trying to initialize a new object of type T. I assume because it doesn't know that it could always initialize that type.

```
    private <T extends G3_gRect> T whatRect(MouseEvent e, List<List<T>> maps) {
        while (!maps.isEmpty()) {
            List<T> map = maps.remove(0);

            for (T entry : map) {
                if(entry.R.contains(e.getPoint())) return entry;                
            }
        }
        return new T(G2_gObj.ObjType.NONE); //return with empty object rather than null.
    }
```

A few of the relevant parts of related classes:

```
public abstract class G2_gObj {

public enum ObjType {
    FUNCTION, RIBBON, D_LINE, D_START, D_END, D_IN_AREA, C_IN_AREA, M_IN_AREA, D_OUT_AREA, M_OUT_AREA, NONE, C_OUT_AREA
}

public ObjType t;

public G2_gObj(ObjType t) {
    this.t = t;
} 
}

public class G3_gRect extends G2_gObj{
public G3_gRect(ObjType t) {
    super(t);
}
}

public class G4_gFunct extends G3_gRect{
public G4_gFunct(ObjType t) {
    super(t);
}
}

public class G4_gDPoint extends G3_gRect{
public G4_gFunct(ObjType t) {
    super(t);
}
}
```

Right now my workaround is to pass in an object of type T into this method to return if nothing is found. It works, its fine, but I imagine there is a better way to actually make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to construct an object without knowing its exact class. Barring the use of reflection, your only option would be to have the caller pass a default value, or to return `null` (which would avoid unnecessary object creation).

If you do want to use reflection (a questionable decision), you can have a parameter `Class<T> clazz`, and return

```
clazz.getConstructor(ObjType.class).newInstance(G2_gObj.ObjType.NONE)
```